# RemixJS nested routes not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I just started a new application using RemixJS on React (with typescript) but my nested pages aren't loading and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm pretty new to Remix so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Folder paths

[image]

**dashboard.tsx**

```
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**dashboard/sales.tsx**

```
export default function Sales() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Nested Sales route</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried importing Outlet from other places, tried changing the names of the folders, watched 1 million videos and read 1 million posts

**Edit 1:** Sorry I forgot to mention, I can access the page `/dashboard` but when I try to access `/dashboard/sales` it gives the `404 Not Found` error

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 versions of the file routing naming convention currently (Remix 1.15.0).

The path that you are describing follows the logic of V1. To make it work, check your remix.config.js file and change the v2_routeConversion to false.

[image]

To see the differences between route file naming between V1 and V2 check below:

V1 -> https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/file-conventions/routes-files

V2 -> https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/file-conventions/route-files-v2

If you would like to see what is going to change with the release of Remix 2.0 so you can future-proof your project check below:

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/pages/v2